# Set my loop according to day name in php

Tags: php, html, loops, calendar, html-table

I am working on a calendar and I have a custom loop with all day name in an array and after getting days in any particular month, I have my loop which will start from 1 to total days.

```
<?php 
   $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
  ?>


 <table border="1">

   <tr>
   <?php foreach($headings as $head){
     echo "<th>".$head."</th>";
 } ?>

  </tr>
 <tr>
 <?php  for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++){

   echo "<td>".$i."</td>";

    if($i%7 == 0){
      echo "</tr><tr>";
   }
}?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now suppose My month start on Friday then my Loop first item starts from Friday. It's currently starting from Sunday for all months. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How many days are in a month? How would you find that out? You need to break this down into smaller problems. You also need to take a closer look at what date functions are available.

Comment: i will find total number of days from `cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,2,1965);`

Comment: `date('w')` will give the integer value of the day of the week - you can use that to find the starting point I should have thought

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for what you want. Hope it will help you. First get start week day of month. And you also need to get total days of that particular month. Here I am giving example regarding current month and year. But you can change it

```
<?php 
   $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
  ?>


 <table border="1">

   <tr>
   <?php foreach($headings as $head){
     echo "<th>".$head."</th>";
 } 
$for_month = date("m");
$for_year = date("Y");
/*$for_month = 02; //You can change this
$for_year = 2017;*/

$start_from =  date('w',strtotime(date("$for_year-$for_month-01")));
$total_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$for_month, $for_year);
 ?>

  </tr>
 <tr>
 <?php  for($i=1;$i<=($total_days+$start_from);$i++){
  if($i>$start_from)
   echo "<td>".($i-$start_from)."</td>";
 else
  echo "<td>"."&nbsp;"."</td>";

    if($i%7 == 0){
      echo "</tr><tr>";
   }
}?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes this works. I also did it with offset. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop based on an offset

```
$offset = 3;

$count = count($headings );
for($i = $offset; $i < $count; $i++)
{
     echo $headings[$i]."<br />";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly read the comment for the explanation

```
        <?php 
  $monthYear = "2017-07"; //get the month
  $fDate =  $monthYear."-01"; //get the starting month
  $sDate = 1; //statically start day
  $eDate = date("t", strtotime($fDate)); //get the last day of the month
   $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
  ?>
 <table border="1">
   <tr>
   <?php
     for($x=0;$x<7;$x++){
        echo"<td>$headings[$x]</td>";
     }
    ?>
  </tr>
    <?php
    $z = 0;
    for($y=$sDate;$y<=$eDate;$y++){

        if($y < 10){
          //proper day initiator format
          $day = "0".$y;
          $date = $monthYear."-".$day; //build the date 
          $test = date("w", strtotime($date));
        } else {
          $day = $y;
          $date = $monthYear."-".$day; //build the date 
          $test = date("w", strtotime($date));
        }


        if($z == 0){
          //this is the initiator to get what day should the calendar start
          echo"<tr>";
          for($w=0; $w<$test; $w++){
            echo"<td></td>";
          }
          echo"<td>$day</td>";
          $z++;
        } else {
          echo"<td>$day</td>";
        }

        if($test == 6){
          //closer and new closer
          echo"</tr><tr>";
        }

        if($y == $eDate){
          //month closer
          echo"</tr>";
        }
     }
    ?>
</table>
```